# Unity Cannot Build WebGL Project

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono

Context: the game is a primitive 2D game just utilizing the 2D rigid body and colliders.
[Screenshot of unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeyIA.png)

**First error:**

Building D:\Downloads\Unity Game Engine\projects\speedrun\Library\Bee\artifacts\WebGL\il2cppOutput\Unity**Class**Registration.cpp failed with output:

'"D:/Downloads/Unity Game Engine/Unity Hub Editor/2021.3.4f1/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/bin/mono"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherBuildProcessor:OpenBuildGameDialog (UnityEditor.BuildTarget) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherBuildProcessor.cs:178)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherWindow:OnWebGLBuildTargetSet () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherWindow.cs:748)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherWindow:OnCreateABuildClicked () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherWindow.cs:509)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherWindow/<>c__DisplayClass75_0:b__0 () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherWindow.cs:627)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

**Second Error** is the exact same except:

Building D:\Downloads\Unity Game Engine\projects\speedrun\Library\Bee\artifacts\WebGL\il2cppOutput\UnityI**Call**Registration.cpp failed with output:

**Third Error**:

BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!

UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <36f62d8e760b48f7af5d32916f997ce1>:0)
UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:158)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <36f62d8e760b48f7af5d32916f997ce1>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <36f62d8e760b48f7af5d32916f997ce1>:0)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerOptions)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherBuildProcessor:OpenBuildGameDialog(BuildTarget) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherBuildProcessor.cs:178)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherWindow:OnWebGLBuildTargetSet() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherWindow.cs:748)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherWindow:OnCreateABuildClicked() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherWindow.cs:509)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.<>c__DisplayClass75_0:b__0() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherWindow.cs:627)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Comment: `'"D:/Downloads/Unity Game Engine/Unity Hub Editor/2021.3.4f1/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/bin/mono"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` says your Unity install is broken or something, like an overly zealous anti-virus program, is preventing mono from running. If you go look in that directory is the mono executable there? Can you run it from a command line?

Comment: Thank you for the fast comment:
1. It is in the directory. 
2. The file type is "file." When I try to run it on the command line it just opens  D:\Downloads\Unity               folder, instead. So I tried running it like this, including the quotations: "D:\Downloads\Unity Game Engine\Unity Hub Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\bin\mono" and it says, including all the characters: ' "D:\Downloads\Unity Game Engine\Unity Hub Editor\2021.3.4f1\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\bin\mono" ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

**Why this is happening?**

This error is occurring because when you are trying to make a build your antivirus is quarantining MonoBleedingEdge.

**The solution:**

To fix this you need to open your antivirus software, go to the quarantine section, find MonoBleedingEdge, restore and make an exception. (you may have to do this again for future builds particularly if you change the build file destination).

Delete the WebGL build files from the last build. Then build again.

I can confirm that uninstalling and reinstalling does fix the problem but you're essentially just reinstalling the whole of unity to get the one missing file.

**Source:**

2 years of uninstalling and reinstalling unity until I decided to follow a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled then re-installed and it somehow fixed it.

Comment: Needs more details, such as how the uninstallation was done

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem @BugFinder suggested deleting the contents of the library folder from my project and rebooting Unity.  That solved the problem for me.